# i want to cache my webview content to load it faster SWIFT3

Tags: ios, swift3

So far I tried this but I getting connection time out error. How to load a web view faster with caching can anyone help?(swift3)

here is my code

```
import UIKit

class test:UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate{
var response: URLResponse?
var error: NSError?
var NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2
var sesson:URLSession!
var progressView:UIProgressView!
var urlData: Data?
var baseURLString: String = "https://google.com"

@IBOutlet weak var SubscribeWeb: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var urlString: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: baseURLString).appendingPathComponent("/").absoluteString

    print("connection urlString = \(urlString)")
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string : urlString)!,
                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad,
                             timeoutInterval: 100.0)
    print("connection request = \(request)")
    // var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString), cachePolicy: URLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil)
    print("connection = \(connection)")
    if (connection != nil) {

        do
        {

            try self.urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: &response)//
            print("self.urlData = \(self.urlData)")
        }
        catch (let e) {
            print("error = \(e)")
        }



        let htmlString = String(data: urlData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        //String(urlData,encode(with: String.Encoding.utf8))
        //  var htmlString = String(urlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let fileUrl = Foundation.URL(string: baseURLString)


        SubscribeWeb.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: fileUrl)
        //SubscribeWeb.loadHTMLString(<#T##string: String##String#>, baseURL: <#T##URL?#>)
    }
    //ara test
    //        let url = NSURL (string: "https://google.com/")
    //        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL,
    //                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad,
    //                                         timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    //       // let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    //        SubscribeWeb.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}    //ara test
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: when I try to load a semi big page into web view it takes time to load. I want to cache the file or do something to make loading of that page into web view faster..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure but you have create .html file in local and write data in this file via URL . may be it is work .

Comment: this sounds logical will try it